# Fastest way to compare millions of rows in one table with millions of rows in another

Tags: java, database, oracle, performance, optimization

I want to compare two tables with million of records in each table and get match data from the comparison.

To get the match data from both the tables we are first comparing the name in `table1` should not be equal to name in `table2`. Then we are comparing city in `table1` should be equal to city in `table2` and then finally we are comparing date_of_birth in `table1` should be with in +-1 year range of date_of-birth in `table2`.

A single row in `Table 1` can have multiple matches with data in `Table 2`.
Also for each match I need a unique Record ID and multiple match data of a single Table 1 row must have same unique record ID.

I tried with Java Code, and PL/SQL Procedure but both are taking hours as this involves comparison of millions of data with millions of data. Is there any faster way to do this matching?

Comment: can you share the columns of the tables and columns on which bases you are comparing those tables.

Comment: To start with, since you already have data in DB, Java is most certainly not the right solution for a comparison. As for DB, such tasks requires more than just tuning the query; the data storage, DB and table definitions, indexes, hardware etc play more important roles. This is a broad area, you should talk to your DBA for this.

Answer (score 3):

> "I tried using java by storing data from both tables in list via jdbc connection and then iterating one list with the other. But it was very slow and took many hours to complete, even got time out exception many time."

Congratulations. This is the first step on the road to enlightenment. Databases are much better at handling data than Java. Java is a fine general programming language but databases are optimized for relational data processing: they just do it faster, with less CPU, less memory and less network traffic.

> "I also created an sql procedure for the same, it was some what faster
>   than java program but still took a lot time (couple of hours) to
>   complete."

You are on the verge of the second step to enlightenment: row-by-row processing (i.e. procedural iteration) is slow. SQL is a set-based paradigm. Set processing is much faster.

To give concrete advice we need some specifics about what you are really doing, but as an example this query would give you the set of matches for these columns in both tables:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from huge_table_1
INTERSECT
select col1, col2, col3
from huge_table_2
```

The MINUS operator would give you the rows in `huge_table_1` which aren't in `huge_table_2`. Flip the tables to get the obverse set.

```
select col1, col2, col3
from huge_table_1
MINUS
select col1, col2, col3
from huge_table_2
```

Embrace the Joy of Sets!

---

> "we are first comparing the name in huge_table_1 should not be equal
>   to name in huge_table_2. Then we are comparing city in huge_table_1
>   should be equal to city in huge_table_2 and then finally we are
>   comparing date_of_birth in huge_table_1 should be with in +-1 year
>   range of date_of-birth in huge_table_2"

Hmmm. Starting off with an inequality is usually bad, especially in large tables. The chances are you will have lots of non-matching names with those matching criteria. But you could try something like this:

```
select * from huge_table_1 ht1
where exists
      ( select null from huge_table_2 ht2
        where ht2.city = ht1.city
        and ht1.date_of birth between add_months(ht2.date_of birth, -12) 
                                  and add_months(ht2.date_of birth, 12) 
        and ht2.name != ht1.name)
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. To get the match data from both the tables we are first comparing the name in huge_table_1 should not be equal to name in huge_table_2. Then we are comparing city in huge_table_1 should be equal to city in huge_table_2 and then finally we are comparing date_of_birth in huge_table_1 should be with in +-1 year range of date_of-birth in huge_table_2.

Comment: I rather disagree with "Databases are much better at handling data than Java". Assuming enough memory and an expensive query (so that data load time doesn't matter), Java can be even faster as it can do all the tricks the DB knows and even more. Obviously, it needs more work and more skill than writing an SQL query, so I definitely agree with you recommending SQL.

Comment: @maaartinus - given sufficient RAM I could read my entire database into the DB Buffer Cache. So I.m not sure that's not a valid argument. And I'm intrigued to know what sort of query you have in mind that would be so much computationally expensive in SQL than in Java that the cost of transporting that data out of the database is trivial in comparison. Obviously there are classes of data which are not well-suited to SQL - graphs are the prime example - but I was careful to say "relational data" :)

Comment: Sure, the DB can also profit from enough RAM, but this wasn't my point (on the opposite, a DB can run well with a smaller RAM). Many queries have super-linear complexity and take longer than a sequential read of all data (the OP's query may qualify). Some queries may profit from indexes created on the fly or only for a part of the data - this is easily done in a programming language and mayn't be supported by your DBMS. +++ Inviting you to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141750/java-vs-sql-performance-in-special-cases

Comment: Thanks again for your help, But I am afraid if this will help me? Actually we are looking for a multiple match with huge table 2 of a single row of huge table 1 i.e. A single Huge table 1 row can have multiple matches with huge table 2. And match data contains columns from both the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Select data from both tables, sorted by the key fields, then iterate them in parallel and compare. Comparison time should be fast, so total run time should be only slightly more than sum of run time for each ordered query.

---

**UPDATE**

[New information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406210/fastest-way-to-compare-millions-of-rows-in-one-table-with-millions-of-rows-in-an/43406256?noredirect=1#comment73873621_43406896) shows that a partial cross-join of the data is desired:

```
left.name <> right.name
left.city = right.city
abs(left.birthDate - right.birthDate) <= 1 year
```

So, given that there is one equality test, you can process the data in chunks, where a chunk is all records with the same `city`.

Comparison will progress as follows:

1. Select data from both tables, sorted by `city`.
2. Iterate both result sets in parallel.
3. Load all records from one result set (`left`) with the next `city`, i.e. load the next chunk. Store them in memory in a [`TreeMap<LocalDate, List<Person>>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).
4. Iterate all records from the other result set (`right`) with the same `city`, i.e. process the chunk.
5. For each record in `right`, find records within 1 year of `birthDate` by calling [`subMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap-K-boolean-K-boolean-), like this:

   ```
   Collection<List<Person>> coll =
           leftTree.subMap(right.birthDate.minusYears(1), true,
                           right.birthDate.plusYears(1), true)
                   .values();
   ```
6. Iterate the records and skip records with same `name`. These are the `left` records that "match" the `right` given record.

   - If needed, you can flatten that and filter the names using stream:

     ```
     List<Person> matches = coll.stream()
             .flatMap(List::stream)
             .filter(p -> ! p.name.equals(right.name))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
     ```

     Optionally replacing the `collect()` with the actual processing logic.
7. When done processing the chunk as described in step 4, i.e. when you see the next `city`, clear the `TreeMap`, and repeat from step 3 for the next chunk, aka `city`.

Advantages of this logic:

- Data is only sent once from the database server, i.e. the repetition of data caused by the partial cross-join is eliminated from the relatively slow data link.
- The two queries can be sourced from two different databases, if needed.
- Memory footprint is kept down, by only retaining data for one `city` of one of the queries at a time (chunk of `left`).
- Matching logic can be multi-threaded, if needed, for extra performance, e.g.

  1. Thread 1 loads `left` chunk into `TreeMap`, and gives it to thread 2 for processing, while thread 1 begins loading next chunk.
  2. Thread 2 iterates `right` and finds matching records by calling `subMap()`, iterating the submap, giving matching `left` and `right` records to thread 3 for processing.
  3. Thread 3 processes a matching pair.

Comment: Now the OP has  provided some details we can see that the comparison involves non-equality and ranges. It's not a fit for line-by-line processing.

Comment: @APC True. For that, "chunk" processing is needed.

Comment: So much more straightforward than a single seven line SQL statement ;)

Comment: @APC Guess that's a matter of interpretation of the question, which just states to find matches according to the 3 key criterias listed above, but doesn't state what to do with matched records. I'm assuming (yes, assuming) that the records from both side of the match is needed, and your 7-line SQL does not provide that.

Comment: Too much is left to assumption: that's why the question got closed. But it's.easy enough to swap the tables around to get the obverse data set. So two seven line statements​ :-D

Comment: @APC I agree with question being unclear, however ;-) running statement again, reversed, will still not give you data in a form where "matching" records can be examined together. Meh, we're likely both wrong, since that matching criteria makes little sense to me. "Match people living in the same city, who are born less than a year apart". Hmmm... When I say it like that, it sounds like a match-making service, and they truly want a cross-join of all "matches", if the two tables are named `males` and `females`.